# Как можно разделить число на цифры в Си или С++?

Tags: c++, c, рекурсия

Например, дано число 12345. Нужно получить 1 2 3 4 5 через рекурсию

Comment: что значит "получить"? вывести? создать массив?

Answer (score 1):

Да нечего делать...

```
void dig(int N)
{
    if (N==0) return;
    int k = N%10;
    dig(N/10);
    cout << k << " ";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    dig(12345);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. ваша функция должна принимать на вход число `n`
2. если разделить `n` по модулю 10, то получится последняя цифра
3. если разделить `n` нацело на 10, то получится число без последней цифры
4. число полученное в п.3) надо передать опять этой же функции (вот и рекурсия)
5. если число 0 - надо прекратить рекурсию
6. чтобы вывести `1 2 3 4 5`, а не `5 4 3 2 1` надо вывести результат определения цифры после вызова функции

Comment: И не забыть, что максимальное отрицательное число это особый случай. Поэтому надо перевести в unsigned и делить уже его

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

void print_digits(int N, const char* sep)
{
    if (N==0) return;
    if (N < 0) printf("-%s", sep); // Печатаем знак, если есть

    int div = abs(N / 10);
    int mod = abs(N % 10);
    
    print_digits(div, sep);   // Печатаем все цифры, кроме последней
    printf("%d%s", mod, sep); // Печатаем последнюю цифру
}

#include <climits>
int main()
{
    print_digits(INT_MIN, ", ");
}
```

[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/Yb57xf)

Comment: Ноль не будет печатать

Comment: @avp, если вы пройдёте по ссылке на godbolt, вы увидите расширенную версию, которая лишена этого недостатка. Просто решил не перегружать ответ лишними подробностями))